# UISearchBar displaying multiple section headers in search results

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have an app that when someone uses the search bar to filter the objects in the UITableView there are two section headers that are displayed.  One is stationary and the other moves with the search results. see two screen shots attached.

below I have included the tableview methods from my app, any help or suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

```
        - (void) performFetch
    {

        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"];  

        // Init a fetch request
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MainObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Apply an ascending sort for the color items
        //NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Term" ascending:YES selector:nil];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
        if(sortValue==1)
        {
            sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fullName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        }
        else if(sortValue==2)
        {
            sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        }
        else if(sortValue==3)
        {
            sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"socialSecurity" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        }
        NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];

        // Recover query
        NSString *query = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text;        
        if (query && query.length) fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(fullName contains[cd] %@) || (socialSecurity contains[cd] %@)",query, query];

        // Init the fetched results controller
        NSError *error;
        if(sortValue==1)
        {
            self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"pLLetter" cacheName:nil];
        }
        else if(sortValue==2)
        {
            self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"pFLetter" cacheName:nil];
        }
        else if(sortValue==3)
        {
            self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"pSLetter" cacheName:nil];
        }

        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:@""]; 
        [self performFetch];
    }

    - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {    
        [self performFetch];
    }
    #pragma mark - Table View

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[__fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sectionInfo name]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    if (index == 0) {
        // search item
        [tableView scrollRectToVisible:[[tableView tableHeaderView] bounds] animated:NO];
        return -1;
    }   
        return index-1;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    // Return the array of section index titles
    NSArray *searchArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
    return [searchArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        if(subtitleValue==1){cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
        else {cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem, and this fixed it: At the end of searching in "performFetch()", don't call tableView.reloadData(), but call

```
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

The reason: After the search, there is a new tableview, see here: [UITableView Plain Style Section Header gets Redrawn on Search View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6971837/1697613).

Answer (score 1):

you need to set only one section instead of "return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];"

Comment: I tried your suggestion I placed a return of '1' instead [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]. this showed only the first section header and no others but still provided the double section header while searching.

Comment: u can try this type of hack to hide ur section header ............ - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
            return 1.0f;
    return 32.0f;
}